# using gdb python api, how to fetch the value of a c variable during debug session

Tags: c, gdb, gdb-python

I am new to gdb python api.
But I am not sure how can I get the get the value of a particular variable during the debug session

```
import gdb

print("Import Sucess")
gdb.execute('b 36')
gdb.execute('r')
gdb.execute('stepi')
#o=gdb.parameter('print check_counter')
print("Check Counter")
print(gdb.value)
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gdb.parse_and_eval](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html) to get a `gdb.Value` with the value of your variable.

For instance, if you have a variable called "v" in your program you can do

```py
v = gdb.parse_and_eval("v")
```

The `v` variable that you get in the gdb's python interpreter is a `gdb.Value` object that you can print, get the value of a field (if the original `v` variable is an object), etc.